# svn command line from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

Hello is there a way to use svn command line from eclipse?

Within eclipse in my project browser i can righclick and then click team and than i have something like svn. Not sure which plugin it is. But it doesn't have button's to for example ignore files for uploading. That's why I want to to it command line. And my question is how to do it.

Ok so how can I use it from command line in windows xp?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish vs. using the actual command line?

Comment: do you mean "is there a way to use svn from eclipse"? you certainly have to communicate your intentions.

Comment: See my answer to see what i mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The plugin you are probably using is [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org). It should have an "Add to svn:ignore" option. If not, try updating to the latest versions of Eclipse and Subclipse. In general subclipse should be enough and there is no need for the command line.

For Windows XP I recommend [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org). It integrates with the Windows Explorer and offers you a graphical environment for all your needs. I would say that is much more stable than subclipse and very easy to use.

If you do want to use the command line tools, download and install svn-win32 from [here](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html). The command line tools could be helpful in merge and copy operations.

I should also point out that none of these methods interfere with each other. You can work with Tortoise SVN or the command line and subclipse won't be affected. All svn clients work by writing and reading from hidden directories called .svn. There is one such directory in every folder under source control. As long as the svn client software is of the same version, an svn client can write to these hidden folders and another one will be able to read from it. A problem could arise if one of the clients is updated to a version that uses a different protocol for writing to the .svn folders. In that case, older clients won't be able to read the information stored there. Upgrading them to the latest version will solve the problem.

Comment: I have turtoise svn. if I do it with svn will my changes be visible within eclispe?

Comment: Yes, the changes will be visible within eclipse. A refresh (F5) may be needed.

Comment: So I'm using Subclipse to manage my code. Question is, how can I open the repository using Tortoise SVN? The only options I see in the Tortoise SVN context menu options involve creating a new repository, which I don't wish to do.

Comment: Answer is quite wrong about Tortoise and Subclipse compatibility, see http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do; sometimes it's better to describe the goal rather than the means you plan to do it.

Have you tried [Subeclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/)? It lets you use SVN inside Eclipse; it's great.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can use it *from* Eclipse, but nothing stops you from just *using* it. From cmd / xterm / whatever. It's not going to interfere with Eclipse in anyway, nor will it interfere with Subclipse (which I'm assuming is what you're using).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using subclipse, and in generaly it works pretty well.

However, and I guess this is your problem, the Team Synchronization by default wants to add **all** files in my projects, not just the ones I add to version control. This is lame and frustrating, and apparently there's no way to turn it off. Screenshots for *older* versions, however, hints at the possibility of turning the "feature" off. Frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not personally a fan of Subclipse - it slows the IDE a bit too much for my taste. Here is an alternative approach using External Tools and TortoiseSVN

1. Create a new External Tool
2. Call it **SVN Commit**
3. Set the Location to \bin\TortoiseProc.exe (mine is C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe)
4. Set the arguments to **/command:commit /path:"${selected_resource_loc}"**
5. Open the file / directory you want committed and run the external tool.

Interchange the **commit** in step four for additional commands. You can also add the specific tools to favorites and have them in a dropdown on the toolbar.
[Additional Arguments Here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-cli-main.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not intended to be too presumptuous here, but I think you should look at whether Subversive or Subclipse actually solves problem in a different way than you intended. For instance, it is very much possible to ignore files and directories from being checked in, via Subclipse.

On the other hand, if you really want to hack away via the command prompt from Eclipse, you must install the [Target Management project](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/) (supported for Eclipse Europa and Ganymede). Once you have that installed, you can launch a remote shell to your local machine and then [type away on the command line](http://dsdp.eclipse.org/help/latest/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.rse.doc.user/gettingstarted/g_start.html) :).

PS: I haven't used this approach ever; Subversive satisfied all my requirements of a SVN plugin in Eclipse.