# GUI And Command line SVN Client

Tags: svn

I think this was asked in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686611/svn-command-line-from-eclipse) but I'm looking for a SVN client that can handle gui and command-line commands.

For example a developer would like a gui to work with but a script would find it easier to issue commands directly on the command line.  Installing one of the gui clients in addition to the svn command line client could lead to a version conflict so I was wondering if there was any client that can handle both.

Comment: I was really hoping for one program to maintain, not two.  But thanks for all the answers!

Comment: I know what you mean but unfortunately I didn't know about the GUI client with embedded command prompt feature.

Answer (score 8):

Just use whatever you like SVN GUI client, and get original SVN client binary from subversion.org. This way you will get GUI and in case if you want command line, just open your command prompt and issue commands directly.
And yes, TortoiseSVN and SVN command-line client don't have any problems with each other.

Comment: I use ToroiseSVN, Collab's SVN command line client, and AnkhSVN.  All of these play nice together.

Answer (score 3):

You don't say which platform, but for Windows the simple solution is to install two clients. I use [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) as a  GUI and [Slik SVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/) as a command line client. They work perfectly well together. Tortoise SVN actually has a command line interface, 
described [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html),  but it is nowhere near as flexible and useful as a dedicated command line client.

Answer (score 1):

The tortoise SVN client for windows is actually invoked from explorer using simple command-line switches.
You can automate these if you want in a script, a little info from the manual:
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html

Answer (score 0):

The [Subclipse plugin](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) for Eclipse allows you to use [JavaHL](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL) to connect to the same Subversion libraries you use in the command line.